# what are these called below that you have thee at the top of the class:

Tags: c#, oop

what are these called below that you have these at the top of the class:

```
using System;
```

Comment: why not read the documentation?

Comment: Handy tip: put your cursor on whatever you want help on (in this case, the word `using`), then press the F1 key to bring up documentation.

Answer (score 0):

These are using directives, see here for a documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: How could there be one? Besides the namespaces from the framework, there are namespaces from the referenced assemblies, and you can define your own.